# Comment tag for bounty giver or post editor

Tags: support, comments

I don't know if it's a missing feature, or a bug. But when someone offers a bounty on someone else's post, you cannot tag them in a comment using @.

Same goes when someone edits a post that is not theirs and they don't leave a comment.

[image]

Comment: An example would be helpful.

Comment: @mins try [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31447/who-is-responsible-for-airspace-separation-when-an-ifr-flight-is-cleared-for-a-v), try a) tag me in a comment since I last edited the question, and b) when Lnafziger had offered a bounty, I couldn't tag him in a comment.

Comment: The same here, neither the editor or the bonus giving person can be included as recipient with @.

Comment: @mins thanks a lot for verifying.

Answer (score 2):

I've asked on MSE's chat and was linked to this [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129232).

You can tag anyone in the revision list (reviewers excluded), but there will be **no autocomplete** (username needs to be typed manually/pasted).

That applies to editors and those who offer bounties.